# ニコ生のユーザー情報を取得するAPIを教えてください

Tags: api

ニコ生のユーザー情報を取得するAPIを教えてください。

■やりたいこと

自分だけでなく他のユーザーの情報も取得したい。
参加コミュニティやお気に入りの一覧を取得したい。

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://osdn.jp/projects/nicolib/wiki/NicoLiveAPI

ここに載っているAPIがすべてかと。
そして、基本的にCokkieのセッション情報が必要。とあることから
各々のセッション情報がなければ実現できないのではないでしょうか。